# Adding jQuery to the DOM via javascript -- doesn't worky

Tags: javascript, jquery, appendchild, createelement

I'm trying to add jQuery to my document through a script but the jQuery library is never found although the script element and it's attributes are attached to the DOM according to firebug. Even after waiting a very long time the library does not come available. What am I doing wrong.

```
    if(typeof jQuery === 'undefined'){
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }
```

Comment: can you give a jsfiddle?..so that we can see what is happening actually

Comment: It works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rBLM4/

Comment: I've waited a long time and it doesn't load. I have two alerts(typeof jQuery);
Try it:

http://oiyc.org/testRecip.html

It does load with Firefox but not Chrome

Comment: What do you mean "waited a long time and it doesn't load"? Did you look at my fiddle? You need to use the `script.onload` method to know when the script has actually loaded, if you have to load it dynamically - that's how asynchronous things work. You can't rely on `alert`. I'm guessing in Chrome, it's blocking the processing of the jQuery file, and Firefox handles it differently. If you go to your website in Chrome, and wait until after the 2 `alert` statements, go to Developer Tools and type in `jQuery`, it prints a function, which means it has been loaded.

Comment: Ian, yes you're correct. I added the script.onload and its working in all browsers except IE8. With that browser I'm getting this:

Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference

Any idea about that error?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rBLM4/1/

The code works fine in jsfiddle but it doesn't run in IE8 or IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Following code copied from some of my code which I think(as this is just for safety) should be working:

```
if (typeof(jQuery.ui) == 'undefined')
{
    var script     = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],

    // Attach handlers for all browsers
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {

         if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
        // callback function provided as param
        if(success != null)
        {
            success();
        }
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
        };              
    };              
    head.appendChild(script);   
}
```

And btw the success is a callback function I defined for real initialization. Like gdoron said you need to wait for it loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. its simple and works fine  ..

```
if(typeof jQuery === 'undefined'){
var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js";
    document.head.appendChild(script);

}
```

Comment: @lan: I tried this code in my system. I got an error on   
`document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);`
statement.
So i tried with 
`document.head.appendChild(script);`
and its got working fine

Comment: IE8 barfs on this:
document.head.appendChild

Answer (score -2):

Instead if using `script.src` try using `setAttribute` function.

```
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src","http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Why? what is the difference?

Comment: @gdoron None, should've been a comment

Comment: @Ian, yes I know... People shouldn't post answer with _try X_ unless they can explain why X *should* or at least *could* work. -1 for the answer.

Comment: `src` is both a [long-documented](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75147231) and universally supported reflected property, using `setAttribute` is completely unnecessary.